# Trying to see the delegate of an NSTextView of an NSCell

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I am having a devil of a time trying to figure out how to get the address of the Text Field Editor (NSTextView) of an NSCell—NSFormCell and NSTextFieldCell in particular? NSCell does not have a property to access it. I did figure out the editor is not allocated until one is actually editing the field.

I want to set the delegate so I can capture keystrokes for auto-completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there's a single field editor for each window. Even if a control or cell uses a custom field editor, it's still vended by the window. You would call `-[NSWindow fieldEditor:forObject:]` to obtain the field editor for a given control.

However, the delegate of the field editor is always set to the control on whose behalf it is working. Setting the delegate to something else is likely to break things. So, you would typically use a custom subclass of the control and implement your delegate methods there.

Finally, controlling completions is normally done using `-textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:` in the text view delegate, not by capturing keystrokes.

Comment: -textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem: just controls the words to present in completions, not the process itself. I'm using that to provide choices for the field. One must call [fieldEditor complete:nil] on each keystroke. But I just discovered that I can put a delegate function, 'controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj' on the controls to capture the keystrokes. I don't have to set the delegate of the field editor after all. My error.

Comment: That being said, inline `-[NSWindow fieldEditor:forObject:]` was what I was looking for. Thanks